# Как проверить являеться ли эллипс который вписанный в прямоугольник кругом?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Как проверить являеться ли эллипс который вписанный в прямоугольник кругом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если эллипс действительно *вписан* в прямоугольник, то гораздо проще проверить, является ли прямоугольник квадратом.

Квадрат - это прямоугольник, у которого все стороны имеют одинаковую длину.

Если же речь идет о "наклонном" эллипсе, то он будет кругом, если касается сторон квадрата в их серединах.

---

> Хорошее решение, но мне нужно проверить является ли эллипс кругом.

*Кхм, кхм... Хорошо.*

Эллипс, вписанный в прямоугольник, является кругом, если прямоугольник, в который вписан эллипс, является квадратом.

Comment: Хорошее решение, но мне нужно проверить является ли эллипс кругом.

Comment: @NazarFernos Если этот вариант не устраивает, то прочитайте определение эллипса, его свойства, и выберите подходящий вариант проверки. Не такая и сложная задача. PS. Кругом эллипс вообще не может быть ни при каких условиях. Эллипс - кривая, круг - фигура. Эллипс может быть только окружностью.

Comment: @NazarFernos таки при чём тут тогда прямоугольник?